# Trick a 32-bit application into running on 64-bit system?

Tags: windows

We have a legacy windows application that checks if it's being run in a 32 or 64 bit system.  Apparently there is no 64 bit version available but we are now faced with a situation where we MUST run it on a 64 bit Windows 7 workstation.  Short of spinning up a 32 bit VM for this purpose does anyone have any suggestions that might workaround this issue?

Comment: Does this legacy Windows application have a name?

Comment: @Michael Hampton - it's a compiled VFP database.

Answer (score 7):

The method I use is flag the desirable application with headers for the 32Bit DLLs, so every time I execute it, the application sees the 32-bit mode DLLs and loads them into its memory space:

1. Download the [Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7 and .NET Framework 4](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279);
2. Install it;
3. Grab Microsoft CorFlags utility named `CorFlags.exe` from the Bin folder of the SDK program files directory;
4. Flag your application to use 32Bit dll's using:

   ```
   CorFlags /32BIT+ yourapplication.exe
   ```

The next time you execute your application, Windows will see the new header and will execute it as a 32-bit application. Your application will use the 32-bit DLL's provided by windows.

Comment: Looks good but the installer quits with an ambiguous error :(

Comment: @Josh What exactly is the error?

Comment: "Installation of the "Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7" product has reported the following error: Please refer to Samples\Setup\HTML\ConfigDetails.htm document for further information."

Answer (score 3):

I know you said you did not want to spin up a VM for this but XP Mode will do exactly what you need, and it can run in a transparent fashion so the app does not appear to be running in a VM.

Install [XP Mode](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/download.aspx/) and see if it fits your needs.

Comment: I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 2):

Visual FoxPro cannot use 64-bit ODBC drivers, even though the app will otherwise run fine on a 64-bit system.

To work around this problem, open an elevated Command Prompt and run `C:\Windows\SysWow64\odbcad32.exe` to set up your DSNs.

(Shamelessly ripped off from [here](http://saltydogllc.com/?p=356).)

Comment: Good thought, I've seen this workaround before with a different database. This particular application doesn't use ODBC data source though, just local files.